# Inline styles and strings in MVC (Views)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ViewModel named HomepageVM containing a list of strings (which hold a location to a specific file - e.g "\images\img.png").

```
public class HomepageVM
{
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to insert the value of those as a background-image property using inline-styles.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Images)
{
    <div style="background-image: url(@(item));"></div>
}
```

For some reason, the result I get inside the browser is "imagesimg.png" instead of "\images\img.png\" even though the value while debugging clearly contains these slashes.

Comment: What do you get if you put the value between the divs for testing?  `>@item</div>` ?

Comment: Why are you using backslashes in the first place? The [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) show forward slashes.

Comment: When I print the value normally, I get the proper value (\images\img.png).

Comment: Set value like this `"/images/img.png"` and see what happens. Also if you open up your network tab and see which request(URL) is ending up with a 404 response, that will help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution was quite simple. Using backslashes was creating the issue where MVC seems to remove them from the output when injected into the inline styles. Replacing them with slashes as mentioned by both mason and Shyju has fixed the issue.